# Cannot redefine a module method in spec_helper.rb

Tags: ruby, rspec, savon

"Some gem" I depend of uses Savon gem.
I need to disable Savon logging, but don't want to mess with "Some gem", and decided to redefine Savon.client(globals, &block) method in `spec_helper.rb` to merge to globals hash log disabling param. But, somehow my code doesn't redefine the module method.

```
    20:     module Savon
    21:       unless Savon.respond_to? :origin_client
 => 22:         binding.pry
    23:         #alias_method :origin_client, :client
    24:         def self.client globals = {}, &block
    25:           binding.pry # <-- doesn't stop here
    26:           globals.merge!(log: false, log_level: :error)
    27:           self.origin_client(globals, &block)

[1] pry(Savon)> Savon.respond_to? :client
```

As shown above, Savon is defined and also has :client method

Here is Savon module definition.

```
module Savon

  Error                = Class.new(RuntimeError)
  InitializationError  = Class.new(Error)
  InvalidResponseError = Class.new(Error)

  def self.client(globals = {}, &block)
    Client.new(globals, &block)
  end

  def self.observers
    @observers ||= []
  end

  def self.notify_observers(operation_name, builder, globals, locals)
    observers.inject(nil) do |response, observer|
      observer.notify(operation_name, builder, globals, locals)
    end
  end

end

require "savon/version"
require "savon/client"
require "savon/model"
```

**UPDATE**:
I tried to redefine Savon.client in before_all trigger, and somehow this didn't work, I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132591/strange-jump-in-pry-when-debugging-spec-helper-rb

Comment: Why you commented the `alias_method` in your example? Are you sure your monkey-patch is loading after Savon?

Comment: I commented it out because it has no relation to the question. Also it doesn't do what I need.

I found that `define_method` wasn't being called.

Comment: So, is it working now? I mean, have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution. I still can't get it working if I try to redefine Savon.client in before_all rspec trigger, but I've could redefine it using new helper file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created a new helper `spec/support/savon_helper.rb` for this, and succeed.

require 'savon'

```
# Enable Savon logging for errors only
module Savon
  unless Savon.respond_to? :origin_client
    class << self
      alias_method :origin_client, :client
    end

    def self.client globals = {}, &block
      #globals.merge!(log_level: :error)
      globals.merge!(log: false) # disable logging completely
      self.origin_client(globals, &block)
    end
  end
end
```